# How to load the link stored in a cell from sql table PHP

Tags: php, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

I am trying to load/generate the link stored inside a cell from my sql table via php.
But I am getting an error:

`Warning: simplexml_load_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in ... on line 78`

Could you guys please tell me where I did wrong?

Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT link FROM previousbroadcast WHERE id=21";             
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$xml = simplexml_load_file($result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$result` is not the value of the link field in your table, but the ressource id. You want something like

```
$sql = "SELECT link FROM previousbroadcast WHERE id=21";
$ressource=mysql_query($sql);  // remember, it's just the ressource
$result = mysql_fetch_array($ressource); // let's get this into an associative array

$xml = simplexml_load_file($result['link']); // and use the respective field in the array to fetch the XML
```

Be aware that this is very simple code, and you should make sure that the file exists before you try to load it...

Comment: thank you so much for helping. i tried this, but instead of loading the link in only row 21, it loads all the links present in the table. why is that?

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, there is no way to tell.

Answer (score 0):

$result variable is a SQL Result set, not a string. You have to use a function like mysql_fetch_array to get the value of the individual columns from your SQL results.

Perhaps something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT link FROM previousbroadcast WHERE id=21";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($row[0]);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query returns a statement handle. You have to fetch a row from that handle and extract the value:

```
$sql = "SELECT ..."
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$xml = simplexml_load_file($row['link']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the result first. In your `$result` variable you only have a SQL resource stored. To get the actual content of the query, use `$result_array = mysql_fetch_array($result)` which will return an array with your data. You can then call the `simplexml_load_file($result_array[0])` function.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query returns a resource. use [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) to get to the content. They have examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT link FROM previousbroadcast WHERE id = '21'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$xml = simplexml_load_file($row['previousbroadcast']);
}
```

Firstly, you should encapsulate your SQL parameters with single quotes ('). Secondly using mysql_query only returns a handle, you need to actually generate an array of that result using mysql_fetch_array(). You should also add in some error-catching as shown above too.